# Iframe onload Animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page that has a form on it. The user enters a URL and that posts to an iframe target.

I just want a loading animation to show while the iframe is loading the new page when the user submits the form. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but this is the code I have, if someone could help :

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function hideLoading() {
            document.getElementById('divLoading').style.display = "none"; 
            document.getElementById('divFrameHolder').style.display = "block"; 
        } 
    </script> 
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <form id="form" method="post" target="my-iframe" convert.php">
            <input id="element_1" type="text" maxlength="255" value="http://"/> 
            <input id="saveForm" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    <div>

    <div>
    <div id="divLoading"> 
        <img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="" /> 
    </div> 

    <div id="divFrameHolder" style="display:none"> 
        <iframe id="my_frame" name="my-iframe" src="page.html" onload="hideLoading()"></iframe>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the example,

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/omohopa/1/edit)

May be i think your function not calling.

Comment: Your script works when you load the page the first time, but it does not work when you hit submit the second time.

However, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a trick:
Inside your `page.html` attach eventlistener of `window.onload` or  `DOMContentLoaded` and fire `parent.hideLoading()` method.

eg.
page.html:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
     parent.hideLoading();
},false);
```